# Custom fonts in a tvOS TVML app

Tags: apple-tv, tvos, tvml

Is there a way to use custom fonts in an `Apple tvOS TVML` based application? I've tried the `@font-face` at-rule to no avail.

```html
<document>
<head>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'My Awesome Font';
        font-weight: 600;
        src: url("${this.BASEURL}/resources/fonts/awesome-font-bold.otf"); 
      }
    </style>
</head>
...
</document>
```

Comment: I would very much like to know this swell. I can't find it mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ITMLStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH11-SW1)
However it is mentioned in the [interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/#typography)

Comment: Guidelines covers tvOS apps in general, Native apps can have any fonts they like.

Comment: Have you read the answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734894/set-font-family-in-tvml/38692663#38692663 ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to set the font-family in tvOS using Apple's provided TVML styles. You can however use the [TVElementFactory class](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLKit/Reference/TVElementFactory_Ref/index.html) to extend upon TVML to create new markup elements.

[This article](https://medium.com/shopgate-mobile-commerce/hacking-tvml-4387e65a9b94#.ihwsdte1b) from Shopgate describes the process. They've also put together a [repository](https://github.com/shopgate/custom-tvml-elements) with a sample project.

Comment: the shopgate it's a very good one however it's in swift and requires some love to integrate.