# Set font family in TVML

Tags: fonts, tvos, font-family, tvml

In my TVML app I am able to set font style properties such as font-size and font-weight using tv-text-style:none, however I am not able to set the font-family property, which seems to be ignored:

```
var Template = function() { return `<?xml version="1.0"    encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<document>  
    <head>  
        <style>  
            .customText {  
                tv-text-style: none;  
                tv-position: center;  
                color: white;  
                font-size: 40px;  
                font-weight: bold;  
                font-family: Courier;  
            }  
        </style>  
    </head>  
    <paradeTemplate>  
...  
                <listItemLockup>  
                    <title>Title</title>  
                    <relatedContent>  
                         <divTemplate>  
                             <title class="customText">abcABC</title>  
                         </divTemplate>  
                    </relatedContent>  
                </listItemLockup>  
...
```

Can I set a font-family different from the system font family?

Thanks for your help,

Luca

Comment: Is there a reason you think this should be possible? I don't see anything in https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ITMLStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH11-SW1 that suggests you get any control over the actual font used.

Comment: `font-family` is listed in the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ITMLStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH11-SW1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use custom font for your title, you should implement custom `TVViewElement` that will use any font. 
First of all, you need to implement your own `TVInterfaceFactory` , it can be done like that (Swift 2 solution for tvOS 9):

```
import UIKit
import TVMLKit

class MyFactory: TVInterfaceFactory {

    override func viewForElement(element: TVViewElement, existingView: UIView?) -> UIView? {

        switch element {

        case let element as MyText where element.elementName == "myCustomText":
            let view = MyTextView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,50))
            view.text = "my text"
            return view

        default:

            break
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

After that you need to implement a custom TVML-item:

```
class MyText: TVTextElement {

    override var elementName: String {

        return "myCustomText"
    }

    var text: String? {

        guard let textValue = attributes?["text"] else { return nil }
        return textValue
    }
}
```

And now you need to implement UIView for your TVTextElement:

```
class MyTextView: UIView {

    var label: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    var text : String {
        get {

            return self.text
        }
        set(value) {

            self.label = UILabel(frame: self.frame)
            self.label.text = value
            self.label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.label.font = UIFont(name: "Your custom font", size: 20.0)
            self.addSubview(self.label)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now you can use your custom item in TVML like that:

```
<myCustomText text="hello world"></myCustomText>
```

Also, don't forget to register you custom item in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
TVInterfaceFactory.sharedInterfaceFactory().extendedInterfaceCreator = MyFactory()
TVElementFactory.registerViewElementClass(MyText.self, forElementName: "myCustomText")
```

Comment: FYI to all, the function that needs to be overrided in the implemented custom TVInterface is now "makeView" not "viewForElement."

Answer (score 0):

`font-family` is now available in TVML. No need to use `TVInterfaceFactory` for custom font support anymore.

Example:

```
tv-text-style: 'none'
font-family: 'Times New Roman'
```

[Apple TV Markup Language Reference: font-family](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ITMLStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015064-CH11-SW34)