# How to add a placeholder image in img tag in TVML?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

Hi I am new a t TVML just want to know how can you load an image in a URL and to have a placeholder image while waiting for the URL.

I'm using the img tag.

Let me know thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems presently this feature is not supported on the TVML side.

You can always file a bug with Apple for this feature in future release.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `TVViewElement` that will add a placeholder image. For more information about the implementation see the post [Set font family in TVML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734894/set-font-family-in-tvml/38692663#38692663) .